# OpenCV 3 and Cuda 7 on openSuse create artifacts on monitor

Tags: c++, opencv

Good evening,

while trying out OpenCV (3.0.0) with Cuda (7.0) on openSuse (13.1), i noticed an interesting behavior. The compilation worked just fine, both for Cuda and OpenCV as well as the tiny test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaarithm.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        cv::Mat src_host, inp = cv::imread("/home/foo/img.jpg", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
        cv::cvtColor(inp,src_host,CV_BGR2GRAY);

        cv::cuda::GpuMat dst, src;
        src.upload(src_host);

        cv::cuda::threshold(src, dst, 128.0, 255.0, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

        cv::Mat result_host;
        dst.download(result_host);

        cv::imshow("Result", result_host);
        cv::waitKey();

    }
    catch(const cv::Exception& ex) {
        std::cout << "Error: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The result also looks just fine as a binary image is created.

My problem is, that multiple artifacts appear on the screen. By artifacts i mean colorful pixels in different locations that can be removed by moving the cursor or windows to update the graphical interface. To me this looks like OpenCV / Cuda writes to graphical memory used by the openSuse GUI.

What do you think and how do i avoid this behaviour?

Comment: does this only happen when using CUDA? try it with a non-CUDA version of the algorithm.

Comment: You are right, it does also happen without CUDA. The problem occurs in the cvtColor function.